# Motor Control using speech

Tags: eclipse, arduino, communication, speech-to-text, sphinx4

My aim is to control a motor using the speech input from the user.
Thus for the speech recognition part i'm using the Sphinx 4 library with Eclipse JAVA IDE (Standard version). My operating system is windows 7. My Recognition part is over so the sphinx 4 program will output the String that the user speaks. 
Next part is to achieve the communication with the control platform (Micro controller). For this i'm planning to use an Arduino Duemilanove or an Arduino UNO. But i cannot figure out how to communicate with the Arduino board or even how to send the recognized String to the Arduino Board. 
Would appreciate if anyone could help me out to over come this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete answer, but rather a pointer for you to explore.

Have a look at [Processing](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Processing). It's an open source toolkit used to make programs communicating with the Arduino. You can probably use it to communicate with Arduino through [serial communication](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/).

Here's a few links you may find interesting as well:

1. [Arduino (processing) Library in Netbeans and control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709792/arduino-processing-library-in-netbeans-and-control)
2. https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=arduino+processing+java&safe=images

Good luck!

Comment: Could you supply me with a example code that i should put in my Java eclipse to send and also in Arduino to receive what i send. Something like sending a string from eclipse and it must be read from Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using G-Code to communicate the desired moves between the host and the Arduino. It is vary established. With plenty of firmware for the Arduino, that interprets it and then moves the motor as how it was requested. Where there are soo many different ways that a set of motor could move and G-Code has a command for each of them.

So your recognition code then simply needs to map the voice request to a corresponding G-code command. You could then either use a grbl shield and grbl firmware on a UNO, or a more supported system such as a RAMPs shield on a MEGA.